# How do I add a value event listener to realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have some images imported to firebase storage and I have added the image links to realtime database under a folder called images. I would like my app to automatically sync images to users once I make changes to the link images in the realtime database. I am not too sure how to add a value event listener and create a database reference.
Currently, I was retrieving the images using the direct link as you can see in the code below. However, this is not working fine as I have to change the links in the code to update new content. Can anyone help on how to go about this? Please share some code that might give me insights on how to achieve this.

imageActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.zamcatalog;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class gameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

 private String[] images = {
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame1.jpg?alt=media&token=b3917686-090f-43fb-852e-0365ac67dd6e",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame2.jpg?alt=media&token=25e4eb76-5361-42a6-9bfd-6e3b1153611f",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame3.jpg?alt=media&token=a5d4c8b9-9ecb-4ea1-a095-557955db1d19",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame4.jpg?alt=media&token=b4598019-13b3-4600-aa49-86fd0a8c5c64",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame5.jpg?alt=media&token=a4991bfe-d3b4-4f1c-be65-55ddfd1de7ba",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame6.jpg?alt=media&token=e8b43bb6-c967-495f-b5e2-336f082225b6",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame7.jpg?alt=media&token=0f135b82-1a05-4585-a511-bbab35a5613a",
            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zamcatalog.appspot.com/o/Game%2Fgame8.jpg?alt=media&token=ab8a9fcf-db2d-4c9c-afd8-969a4db22a8c"
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(gameActivity.this,images);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.zamcatalog;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
        import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
        import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
        import com.firebase.ui.storage.images.FirebaseImageLoader;
        import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
        import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    String[] images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, String[] images) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container, false);

        ImageView image;
        image = (ImageView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        DisplayMetrics dis = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dis);
        int height = dis.heightPixels;
        int width = dis.widthPixels;
        image.setMinimumHeight(height);
        image.setMinimumWidth(width);

        try {
            Glide.with(activity.getApplicationContext())                     
                    .load(images[position])  
                    .into(image);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        container.addView(itemview);
        return itemview;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your image returns 403, Permission Denied.

Comment: I changed the images so those links are no longer valid. Just had them there for illustration purposes of how the code looks.

Comment: Oh, Okay.. I think you should try the below answer snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You should store those images in your database, first get the link of them and then retrieve those images with [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

This snippet saves an image into the storage and gets its download URL:

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file); //your image

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            //Here you can write that url to your database like this
             yourDatabaseRef.push().child("photo").setValue(downloadUri);
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

then you retrieve that link with an **addValueEventListener**

```
// Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
yourImageRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String photoUrl = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    //Manage picasso or glide to load that url

       //Glide example
      GlideApp
           .with(Context)
           .load(photoUrl)
           .centerCrop()
           .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
           .into(myImageView);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
  }
});
```

We store the image URL in order to show it with Picasso or Glide, this is the easiest way to load images with Firebase.